# QGIS 2.6 summarizing area (m²) for current atributes

Tags: qgis, area, qgis-2.6

If I have a code for each polygon and I have counted the area in m² for each of them (all this information is in single columns). How can I summarize these areas by codes (for example summarize all areas with code 100 etc.) in QGIS 2.6.1.?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the **Group Stats** plugin which you may need to download and install from the toolbar: *Plugins* > *Manage and Install Plugins*. I used it for a simple layer populated with some basic data:

[image: Example layer]

Below is the interface of the **Group Stats** plugin which calculates the *sum* of the `Area` column. It only sums those features which contains a value of 100 for the `Code` column.

[image: Group Stats plugin]

Hope this helps!