# Summarizing entries by column using QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I have one field named (OBID) identificator of an municipal. Second field is ZAPOSL which indicates the number of employees in several stores in this municipal.

I wolud like to summarize all employees in each municipal.

Example: If the municipal ID is for example 55, QGIS should sum all ZAPOSL numbers which correspond to the OBID = 55.

See figure: OBID = 55: ZAPOSL: 2+0+18+4+8+0+4 = 36

ArcView knows that as Summarize and creates a new table with the result...

[image]

Comment: You can use the **Group Stats** plugin which should allow you to perform SUMS based on specific field values. You can find a similar question [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139201/qgis-2-6-summarizing-area-m%C2%B2-for-current-atributes). Hope this helps!